# Can I use Apple Car Play to get me the car VIN Number

Tags: carplay, vin

I'm in the discovery stages of an extension to my application. I'm looking to enable my app to work with Apple CarPlay. I'm looking to see if a user plugs in their phone, can I get a VIN Number from the car?

Comment: I would suggest the answer is "no", as the CarPlay does not interact with the car at all (beyond the stereo), in fact, it's your phone which provides all the functionality to the head unit (I assume through something like the devices multi screen support, but I'm not familiar with how it all works at a technical level)

Comment: If you're really interested in this kind of thing, most cars now days have a diagnostic port (which is used by the service centres to get diagnostic information from the on-board systems), there are several which support bluetooth - [a bit of googling](https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&ei=BMvUXOCMI-jg0gKTtKlQ&q=car+diagnostic+port+bluetooth&oq=car+diagnostic+port+bl&gs_l=psy-ab.1.0.0i22i30.25369.31264..31976...1.0..0.257.2959.2-13......0....1..gws-wiz.......0i71j0i67j0i131i67j0j0i20i263j33i160.HXT9wp9VG6g) or even [this](https://automatic.com/how-automatic-works)

Comment: Yeah, they do. I'm researching Audi/ VW specifically (since I used to work there in ops) and the Audi MMI systems do store the VIN number, so I might be something to explore and see if they will let the app pull that data rather than using Apple CarPlay.

Comment: You’ll probably find that it’s a “dedicated” feature of the head unit and not part of CarPlay api exposes by Apple